# How to write given state in reducer with immutable.js?

Tags: javascript, redux, immutability, reducers

How would i convert this with usage of Immutable JS.

fromJS to wrap initial state and setIn method for nested cases.

```
const initialState = {
    allMovies: [] 
};

const movieReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
   const {type, payload} = action;
    switch (type) {
       // some actions...
       case movieActionTypes.FETCH_MOVIES_SUCCESS: {
           return {
               ...state,
               allMovies: {
                   ...state.allMovies,
                   [payload.movie.id]: {
                       ...state.allMovies[payload.movie.id],
                       ...payload.movie,
                       ready: false,
                   },
               },
           };
       }
       default:
           return state;
    }
};
```